# Data Class Equality in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hello everyone I am trying to use the `==` to check if two variables are structurally equal

```
// PersonImpl0 has the name variable in the primary constructor
data class PersonImpl0(val id: Long, var name: String="") {
}

// PersonImpl1 has the name variable in the body
data class PersonImpl1(val id: Long) {
     var name: String=""
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val person0 = PersonImpl0(0)
    person0.name = "Charles"

    val person1 = PersonImpl0(0)
    person1.name = "Eugene"

    val person2 = PersonImpl1(0)
    person0.name = "Charles"

    val person3 = PersonImpl1(0)
    person1.name = "Eugene"

    println(person0 == person1) // Are not equal ??
    println(person2 == person3) // Are equal ??

 }
```

Here the output I got

```
false
true
```

Why is it that the 2 variables are not equal in the first case and equal in the second case ?

THank you for clearing this up for me

Comment: You know that you never set `person2.name` or `person3.name` to anything though?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kotlin compiler generates `hashCode` and `equals` methods for data classes, including properties in the constructor only. The property `name` in `PersonImpl1` is not included in the `hashCode`/`equals`, hence the difference. See the de-compiled code:

```
  //hashcode implementation of PersonImpl1
  public int hashCode()
  {
    long tmp4_1 = this.id;
    return (int)(tmp4_1 ^ tmp4_1 >>> 32);
  }

  //equals implementation of PersonImpl1
  public boolean equals(Object paramObject)
  {
    if (this != paramObject)
    {
      if ((paramObject instanceof PersonImpl1))
      {
        PersonImpl1 localPersonImpl1 = (PersonImpl1)paramObject;
        if ((this.id == localPersonImpl1.id ? 1 : 0) == 0) {}
      }
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much . Also how do you see the decompiled kotlin code in Android Studio / IntelliJ ?

Comment: @Charles-EugeneLoubao I use [JD GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) to de-compile `class` files to java source code.

Comment: You can also use open a .kt file in Android Studio and then Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode. In the right panel the bytecode will appear and can also be decompiled to Java using the 'Decompile' button.