# Difference in the equality operators ,incase of Data class and Regular class

Tags: kotlin

Using Data class and normal class produces different output .What is the reason behind it ?

```
data class User(val a:String)                   
val obj1 = User("asd")
val obj2 = User("asd")
if(obj1 == obj2) println("true")    
if(obj1===obj2) println("true")
if(obj1.equals(obj2)) println("true")

//this gives the output of true for 1st and 3rd print statement.
```

Using regular class

```
class User(val name: String)
val obj1 = User("asd")
val obj2 = User("asd")
if(obj1 == obj2) println("true")
if(obj1===obj2) println("true")
if(obj1.equals(obj2)) println("true")

//this does not print anything.
```

Comment: Kotlin generates an `equals()` method using constructor parameters of a data class ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data Class Equality in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350146/data-class-equality-in-kotlin)

Comment: "_this gives the output of true for all print statement_" – It should not print anything for `if(obj1===obj2) println("true")`, and doesn't when I tried it, as the two variables do not reference the exact same object.

Comment: @slaw My bad I did some mistake while copy pasting .  I have updated it now .

Answer (score 0):

Data class compare the content of the instance (in case of different pointer address), not like regular class (compare pointer address only)

You can check detail implementation for data class from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44350193/13496611)

Comment: Even for a regular class, `==` will call the `equals` method. It's just that, in the case of the code given by the OP, that means `Any.equals` is called. That implementation is the same as using `===` (i.e., reference equality). But the regular `User` class could override the `equals` method. Data classes do this for you automatically (where the implementation is based on the primary constructor's properties).